# can only read folder/directory from main() ? listfiles() returns null?

Tags: java, file

I'm working on a Netbeans java project using `jdk 1.8 x64` on a x64 windows OS
My problem is: "reading a directory's content (only files) with the method `file.listfolders()` outputs null if called from my `TextProcessor` class instance. However, changing the method to `static` and calling it from a `main()` works perfectly, so it has nothing to do with permissions as far as I understand.

```
private List<String> get_files_paths(String data_path) {
    File folder = new File(data_path);
    List<String> full_paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (!fileEntry.isDirectory())
            full_paths.add(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return full_paths;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your method cannot return null. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for your reply, I assume you've tried it or already have prior experience and never got the "null" from reading a file in a non-static way, I however, am getting "null" and I was hoping someone would've faced this issue and found a solution.

Comment: You say it works in some cases but not in others - but you have not shown the corresponding code. It is very likely that the problem is in the code that you haven't shown. You need to show a *complete* example that reproduces the problem. See the link I posted above.

Comment: TextProcessor p = new TextProcessor("E:\\TEST","E:\\Dist",5);
            TextProcessor o = new TextProcessor("‪‪E:\\TEST","‪E:\\Dist",4);
now with 'p' it works as it should, but with 'o' it throws a null ptr exception, really odd !

Comment: after I copied the 'p' line and pasted it in the 'o' line and changed the variable name back to 'o' it works ! 
please bare in mind that I did not change any of the params 
I don't know what caused it but it is now solved thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works fine, as long as path is correct. I assume your path must be invalid. As File::listFiles will return a null, if directory does not exist.

```
private List<String> get_files_paths(String data_path) {
    File folder = new File(data_path);
    if(!folder.exists() || !folder.isDirectory()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid directory");
    }
    List<String> full_paths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isFile())
            full_paths.add(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return full_paths;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, as I said, the method works in a " non-static " context (through main() ) and it outputs me the files I have in that directory, with the private one however, it gives me a null pointer exception when it gets called from the class constructor to append it to List<String> paths variable. To be precise it's the folder.listFiles() that returns a null pointer exception and not "get_files_paths()" .

Comment: Can you show in which line this NPE is thrown? add method in List accepts nulls, so the only possible place is in folder.listFiles().

Comment: I tried with the given solution and it doesn't output a problem for a variable 'p' but for 'o' it does for the following test:
            TextProcessor p = new TextProcessor("E:\\TEST","E:\\Dist",5);
            TextProcessor o = new TextProcessor("‪‪E:\\TEST","‪E:\\Dist",4);
exception is at:
 if(!folder.exists() || !folder.isDirectory()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid directory");

Comment: after I copied the 'p' line and pasted it in the 'o' line and changed the variable name back to 'o' it works ! please bare in mind that I did not change any of the params I don't know what caused it but it is now solved thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, but it's really odd !! I was doing this before:
-I got the path from where I wanted to get files by rightclicking on the folder -> properties. I got "E:\TEST" when pasted into NetBeans.
Now, I do the following:
-I write the value with the keyboard in NetBeans IDE like this: "E:\TEST" (the same)
and it works !! I really don't know why this happened ?!